# Eliminate numbers from a mix of numbers and letters from a list of strings

Tags: python-3.7

I'm pretty new to programming and I need help.

```
list = ["defew21", "dldapl43, "vdvc3232"]
```

I need to eliminate all the numbers from the above list to return a list like this

```
list1 = ["defew", "dldapl", "vdvc"]
```

I have tried several ideas but of no avail.

Comment: Welcome ronnie900 :) Could you include what you have tried? Please do so not in the comments but by editing your question